# Ubuntu16.04 cannot connect to mobile hotspot

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am running ubuntu mate 16.04.

Wifi connection to school wifi or just regular wifi works perfectly fine.

However, connecting to mobile hotspot does not work... along with portable wifi router.

Does anybody ran into same issue? any help would help me..

Answer (score 0):

Okay get this

Turns out (Presumably) raspberry pi cannot handle wireless protocol provided by Korean carriers (I use Pocket wifi from SKTelecom which is mobile router that transforms LTE signal to wifi). I tried pretty much every solutions online but in vain.

The solution was :
USB tethering.
I simply connected router to raspberry pi and it worked!
For those who are considering hotspot connection or wireless router, consider USB tethering.
All praise micro 5 pin..